# Bootstrap tooltip : hide tooltip if binding variable value is null

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, haml, angularjs-ng-if

I'm working with angularJS and haml syntax and I want to hide the tooltip on mouse hover if an attribute is null, this the line that show it :

```
%td
            %a{ ng_href: '/reports/{{decoratedReport.id}}/download'}
              %i.fa.fa-download.fa-lg.dark-grey{ uib_tooltip: " {{'reports.downloaded_at' | translate}}  {{ decoratedReport.last_downloaded_at | date: ('report.download_date.format.short' | translate ) }}",
                                                 tooltip_placement: 'left'}
```

how to add an ng_if condition inside the haml to hide just the tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is : tooltip-enable="flag" where flag is a Boolean value set in your controller